# do i need to remember the password for wallet recovery?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, mnemonic-seed

trying to clarify something. To recover a wallet I just need my 25 mnemonic seed correct? I don't need the password right？

thanks

Answer (score 6):

Correct.  If you need to recover from seed, it means the old wallet file is gone.  The wallet file is what is locked with a password.  When you recover from seed, it will generate a new wallet file, and you'll be prompted to add a password for the new wallet file.